# Add unique ID to identical links for tracking campaign value return

Tags: javascript, arrays, adobe-analytics

I am attempting to get all links on a page where the link name and href are the same and assign a value to the return name to make the reference to that link unique.

So if a page had the following three identicial links:

```
            <a href="link1" class="adobeTrackedCustomLink">About Us</a>
            <a href="link1" class="adobeTrackedCustomLink">About Us</a>
            <a href="link1" class="adobeTrackedCustomLink">About Us</a>
```

The expected result if second link clicked the return would be:

> aboutus-link1-2

I can get the link name and href returned as below:

```
            var linkname = $(input).text().trim().replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();
            var hrefname = $(input).closest('a').attr("href").replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();
            return linkname + '-' + hrefname;
```

But I don't know how I would do the ID on the end, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your current code appears to be using jQuery?

Comment: I assumed it was using pure JavaScript, if this doesn't look like the case please reply with a jQuery solution to try.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a vanilla js solution. It might be a little verbose, but you can get the id like this:

```
var q = document.querySelectorAll('.adobeTrackedCustomLink');

for(var i = 0; i<q.length; i++){
      q[i].id = i; 
      var linkname;
      var hrefname;
      var id;
      q[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                linkname = this.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
                hrefname = this.getAttribute('href');
                id = Number(this.id);
                console.log("New Name",  linkname+"-"+hrefname+"-"+(Number(id)+1));
      })
 }
```